# error 6 when uploading json in watson discovery service

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-discovery

when uploading a json sample document in watson discovery service, via the tool to create, i get this response:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error": "6"
}
```

I tried stripping my whole json, so thats there are no strange characters. e.g.

```
[
  {
    “text”: "JDE Reset JDE password",
    "FunctionName": "ERP"
  }
]
```

i thought error 6 was for unsupported characters, but not sure anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just with:

```
{
    "text": "JDE Reset JDE password",
    "FunctionName": "ERP"
  }
```

if dont work, test with:

```
 {
        "Content-Type: application/json"
        "text": "JDE Reset JDE password",
        "FunctionName": "ERP"
      }
```